# 'Array' showing in my foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

For some reason I'm getting the word 'array' as an output when I try to do a foreach to echo out the values in an array (there are 2 values). These show fine if I use print_r in the array so I know they are there. I've also tried using as list but that only shows the first value and nothing after it.

It's getting late so it might be something pretty silly! Thanks in advance

```
<?php

$crawl_url = "./emails.php";

function get_email($url) {
    $input = @file_get_contents($url);
    $regexp = '/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i';
    preg_match_all($regexp, $input, $matches);

    if (empty($input)) {
        echo "No email addresses found";

    }   
    else {
        foreach($matches as $matches_values) {
            print $matches_values;
        }
    }
}

get_email($crawl_url);
echo '<br /> function complete';
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing the 0 index on $matches.

Try this :

```
foreach($matches[0] as $matches_values) {
    print $matches_values;
}
```